# After update to new version of react native Ionicons (in react-native vector icon ) Not working in Ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-vector-icons, ionicons

It's working fine in android . I added fonts in Info.plist.

Also added
"apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle" "
in android/app/build.gradle.

all other fonts are working fine both ios and Android.[image: Ionicons showing question mark in ios]

Answer (score 0):

That an issue
you need to follow this step
type this in terminal

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

if pod get install successfully then run this

```
 npx react-native run-ios
```

It will get work fine then also it get issue then try to get on old version of it.

Comment: pod install ,pod update nothing fixing this error

Comment: Try to install old  version of react native vector .which you where using before.

Comment: ya it's working in old react-native version.I want this working in new version

Comment: Take backup of code and try to uninstall react-native ionicons and install latest version of it.